# Register collection with Simple Injector

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, simple-injector

I try to register a collection with simple injector in c#. My approach was the following:

```
container.Collection.Register<IValidateMitarbeiter>(
    typeof(MitarbeiterVerfuegbarkeitValidator),
    typeof(MitarbeiterQualifikationsValidator));
```

But i get this error message:

> The configuration is invalid. Creating the instance for type IDispoLinienManager failed. The constructor of type DispoLinienManager contains the parameter with name 'mitarbeiterValidators' and type IValidateMitarbeiter that is not registered. Please ensure IValidateMitarbeiter is registered, or change the constructor of DispoLinienManager.

This is the constructor of DispoLinienManager

```
public DispoLinienManager(IDataContextFactory dataContextFactory,
        IDispoPlanLinieFactory dispoPlanLinieFactory,
        IValidateMitarbeiter mitarbeiterValidators)
    {
        this.dataContextFactory = dataContextFactory;
        this.dispoPlanLinieFactory = dispoPlanLinieFactory;
        this.mitarbeiterValidators = mitarbeiterValidators;
    }
```

IValidateMitarbeiter has two implementations who are both used in DispoLinienManager. 
If there are any missing informations, i will be glad to help you to solve my problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I reproduce your example locally, using the latest version of Simple Injector, I get the following message:

> The configuration is invalid. Creating the instance for type DispoLinienManager failed. The constructor of type DispoLinienManager contains the parameter with name 'mitarbeiterValidators' and type IValidateMitarbeiter that is not registered. Please ensure IValidateMitarbeiter is registered, or change the constructor of DispoLinienManager. **There is, however, a registration for IEnumerable<IValidateMitarbeiter>; Did you mean to depend on IEnumerable<IValidateMitarbeiter>**?

Do note the last part of that message.

As described [here](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/decisions.html#separate-collections) in the documentation, Simple Injector separates registration of collections from one-to-one mappings:

> When designing Simple Injector, we made a very explicit design decision to define a separate **RegisterCollection** method for registering a collection of services for an abstraction.